# How to prevent design-time errors caused by d:DataContext binding

Tags: wpf, mvvm, design-time

It is rather convenient to attach a ViewModel to a View with
`d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance ViewModel}"`, however in this case the View designer starts to create an instance of the ViewModel and crashes itself with exceptions.

For example, I have a command in the ViewModel which availability depends on stats loaded from a database. The visual designer cannot load the stats, and stats remain `null`, so the command throws an exception and the designer crashes.

Is there an option to overcome this, or do I have to remove that binding to the ViewModel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you set `IsDesignTimeCreatable` in your DesignInstance markup, it won't actually instantiate the data context class via its constructor.  It will merely create an instance with the same 'data shape'.  The default contents of this faux data shape can contain nulls, so where you need to fix things is in the classes that consume the data context, so that they don't crash the designer if the data is uninitialized.

Comment: I found that the cause was a command availability checking method that was determining whether the command was available or not. This method uses the data that cannot be obtained in design-time. The command is bound to a button in the main window, and the designer tries to evaluate the command availability. I have applied a fix to a command infrastructure so that it always returns `true` for a command availability in design-time, but the question is why the designer needs the command availability and calls that method in design-time... `d:DataContext` was not the cause, just as you said.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you have a separate viewmodel for design (a stub) that returns test data.
You can inherit from your real ViewMOdel and set up dummy defaults or have an entirely separate ViewModel with the same named properties.

I usually find its a good idea in WPF to initialize everything to some default value

Answer (score 1):

well the constructor of your view model is tiring to construct the data context at the design time and getting failed.

one cause might be.
might be you are using some data connection from configurations .

the simplest way is to put your constructor code of view model into try catch block and the better to check where its getting failed.

like

```
public class myViewmodel()
{
 public myViewmodel()
{

try
{
// build your data context.
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
//show the messages
}

}
```

}